div not rendering react
I'm trying to add a React component to a webpage following this documentation: https://react.dev/learn/add-react-to-an-existing-project
I import the JS file in the HTML page like so:
<script src="./contact.js" type="module"></script>

With type="module" I get the error Unexpected token '<'. Without that, I get the error SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'. import call expects one or two arguments.
The .js file is below:
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';

// Clear the existing HTML content
document.body.innerHTML = '<div id="app"></div>';

// Render your React component instead
const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('sec1'));

root.render(<h1>Hello, world</h1>);

I have a div in the HTML file:
<div id="sec1"></div>

The HTML, JS file, package file, and node_modules folder are all in the same directory. I'm not sure as to why nothing's rendering.

From the docs you linked... If it causes a syntax error, you might need to transform your JavaScript code with Babel, and enable the Babel React preset to use JSX.

the possible mistakes could be

are you using a bundler like vite , parcel or webpack ?
if not than you need to add babel to compile the jsx or add this to your html head tag

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

2.as you have cleared your body by changing its innerhtml so the div named sec1 is gone
and at this step const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('app'));
you have to do const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('sec1'));

I tried both  <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script> and <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>, and declared the JS file like so: <script src="/contact.js" type="text/babel"></script> but now I get the error "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require". I also tried implementing the babel code in my contact.js file
